# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Middleware returns 404

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I decided to make a custom middleware for ASP.NET API core 2.1.

```
public class AuthorizeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly AuthorizeOptions _options;

    public AuthorizeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, AuthorizeOptions options)
    {
        _next = next;
        _options = options;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        bool hasRole = false;
        if (hasRole)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Not authorized, you need role: {_options.Role}");
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

    }

}        
public struct AuthorizeOptions
{
    public AuthorizeOptions(string role)
    {
        Role = role;
    }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use this middleware in my Application.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseRouter(AuthenticatedRoutes(app));

        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private IRouter AuthenticatedRoutes(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {

        IRouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder(applicationBuilder);

        builder.MapMiddlewareGet("/api/values", appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<AuthorizeMiddleware>(new AuthorizeOptions("User"));
            appBuilder.UseMvc();
        });

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

This works just fine but when I remove appBuilder.UseMvc(); from MapMiddlewareGet and the specific route my function call returns 404.

I tried to put the appRouter above app.useMvc(). Without success, my middleware next function still returned 404 when _next.Invoke() was called.

So why does the useMvc() work whenever I call it in the appBuilder, Am I doing something that is considered bad practice, and why do i have to app.useMvc() in MapMiddlewareGet()?

Comment: Try to read this it may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your `AuthenticatedRoutes()` tries to do is to build a router with middlewares, thus we can use the finally returned IRouter as a `RouterMiddleware` to process a request. **However, `RouterMiddleware` will never continue to route once there's already a handler matched**. As a result, it will not "dispatch" requests from one `RouterMiddlware` to another `RouterMiddleware` automatically.

Let's review your code:

```
app.UseRouter(AuthenticatedRoutes(app));
```

As you know, the method `app.UseRouter()` here is an extension method which simply **Use the `RouterMiddlware`**. So the first question will be: How the router middleware works? Let's look into the source code:

```
public class RouterMiddleware
{
    private readonly IRouter _router;

    // ...

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var context = new RouteContext(httpContext);
        context.RouteData.Routers.Add(_router);
        await _router.RouteAsync(context);
        if (context.Handler == null){
            _logger.RequestDidNotMatchRoutes();
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        } else {
            httpContext.Features[typeof(IRoutingFeature)] = new RoutingFeature(){
                RouteData = context.RouteData,
            };
            await context.Handler(context.HttpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here, the `RouterMiddleware` routes against a context and check if there's a `RouterHandler` matched:

1. If there's none, **do nothing and then dispatch the request to next middleware**.
2. Else, handle the request with the `RouterHandler`. **Note that it will never dispatch the request to next middleware**.

Let's review how your router and `RouterHandler` works:

```
private IRouter AuthenticatedRoutes(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{

    IRouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder(applicationBuilder);

    builder.MapMiddlewareGet("/api/values", appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseMiddleware<AuthorizeMiddleware>(new AuthorizeOptions("User"));
        appBuilder.UseMvc();
    });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

See that? Your route will check if the HTTP method is `HttpGet` and if the url could match `/api/values`:

1. If so, it means that the route is matched, and a specific `RouterHandler` will be invoked to process the request.

   - The `RouterHandler` will firstly invoke the Middleware of `AuthorizeMiddleware`
   - if you add a `appBuilder.UseMvc();`, it will then invoke the action matched
   - if there's no `appBuilder.UseMvc();`, it will terminate further process, and finally results a `404` response.
2. If not, it means that the router here is not matched, and will do nothing and then dispatch the request to next middleware.